# server-based email attachements

Tags: codeigniter, email, attachment

I'm using codeigniter to work on an intranet based system that will allow users from within the company to send price sheets and marketing materials to our clients via a codeigniter based mailing system.

I'm able to send an email just fine without adding the line

```
$this -> email -> attach('/uploads/'.$file_name.$file_extension);
```

The uploads are added by staff members and put into an 'uploads' folder that's in public_html.

I store the file's information in a database table and then call it to get the required name and extension when I'm going to send the email. I've already tested to make sure that it's pulling the right name and extension from the database.

I still keep getting an error that says:

```
Unable to locate the following email attachment: /uploads/company_canadian_catalog.pdf
220 smtp.mandrillapp.com ESMTP 
hello: 250-ip-10-33-129-14
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 26214400
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250 8BITMIME
from: 250 2.1.0 Ok
to: 250 2.1.5 Ok
data: 354 End data with .
250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as A20963C201A 
quit: 221 2.0.0 Bye
Your message has been successfully sent using the following protocol: smtp
User-Agent: CodeIgniter
Date: Wed, 3 Sep 2014 12:24:55 -0700
From: "me" <my_company@email.com>
Return-Path: <my_company@email.com>
To: me
Subject: =?utf-8?Q?TESt?=
Reply-To: "my_company@email.com" <my_company@email.com>
X-Sender: my_company@email.com
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)  
Mime-Version: 1.0
```

The uploads folder clearly works because I've been successfully able to send files to it and store said files information in the database. I can also download the files fine on the front end when I click on a generated link.

I've exhausted by google-foo resources and have turned to the wise inter-webs gurus of stack overflow. Please let me know my minuscule and tiny mistake that will make me forever want to stub my pinky toe on my bed frame.

**EDIT:** I have also put:

```
$this -> email -> clear(TRUE);
```

at the beginning of my function

Answer (score 0):

> The uploads are added by staff members and put into an 'uploads' folder that's in public_html.

If that 'uploads' directory is a sub-directory of 'public_html', then '/uploads/' couldn't possibly be pointing to it. '/uploads/' is an absolute path, while you're trying to use it as a relative one.

The solution is simple, just use the right directory path.

If you have your application/ directory is *inside* public_html/ as well, then you need this:

```
FCPATH.'/uploads/'
```

If application/ directory is *at the same level* as public_html/ (it should be, for security purposes), then:

```
APPPATH.'/uploads/'
```

Comment: my application is at the same level as public_html-> which houses uploads. APPATH.'/uploads/' did not work. even after copying and pasting the name of the file I was trying to send. I thought hard-coding would at least give me some result, but instead all I get is an email with a subject, no body text and no attachment.